# Eliminating duplicate values using PHP

Tags: php

How can I eliminate duplicate in an array using PHP, array looks like below

```
[1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Dean
            [s_id] => 1
            [surname] => 
            [id_nr] => 84934568321
            [student_nr] => 0
            [createdate] => 0000-00-00
            [enddate] => 0000-00-00
            [count_absent] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Dean
            [s_id] => 1
            [surname] => 
            [id_nr] => 84934568321
            [student_nr] => 0
            [createdate] => 0000-00-00
            [enddate] => 0000-00-00
            [count_absent] => 3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [name] => Dean
            [s_id] => 1
            [surname] => 
            [id_nr] => 84934568321
            [student_nr] => 0
            [createdate] => 0000-00-00
            [enddate] => 0000-00-00
            [count_absent] => 3
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [name] => Dean
            [s_id] => 1
            [surname] => 
            [id_nr] => 84934568321
            [student_nr] => 0
            [createdate] => 0000-00-00
            [enddate] => 0000-00-00
            [count_absent] => 3
        )
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use `array_unique($array)` in PHP

you can also iterate over array and compare manually

Answer (score 3):

[`array_unique`](http://docs.php.net/array_unique)

Answer (score 3):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

```
$input = array("a" => "green", "red", "b" => "green", "blue", "red");
$result = array_unique($input);
print_r($result);
```